# Integrating with salesforce

Tags: soap, salesforce

I am trying to figure out as to how partner apps can integrate with salesforce. E.g. https://vimeo.com/85938111. Here you can see that there is contextual navigation from the salesforce Opportunity UI to the partner app and then at the end of the demo the partner app posts data back to salesforce object. I would like to understand as to whether this type of integration uses:

- Client side API (SOAP Ajax API) to update the Opportunity that is currently loaded in the UI or does it use some kind of server side integration (partner app consuming the SOAP API from their server side).
- How is the UI refreshed to show the partner app update on the UI ?

Answer (score 0):

That looks like custom VisualForce installed via an App Exchange app.  So no SOAP necessary.